# addClass not working, Trying to add a class depending on the URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the first time I'm submitting a query, So sorry if the Format isn't right.Please hep me out with it..:)

Once the mail is sent, I'm retrieving the word "submitfunc" from the URL and adding the Class to remove the Form. 
The mail is being sent successfully and even the alert message is being displayed, So the control is flowin in the 'if condition', but the Class isn't being added.

```
<!--STYLES-->
<style>
   .mailSent
   {
    display:none;
   }
</style>

<!--HTML FORM-->
<div id="ContactForm" class="content col-lg-5">
    <form action="?action=submitfunc" method="post" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">
        <!--The regular Form-->
    </form>
</div>

<--JAVA SCRIPT-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var first = getUrlVars()["action"];
    });

    if (first == 'submitfunc') 
    {
       alert("This alert messgae is being displayed!!");
       $('#ContactForm').addClass('mailSent');
    }

    function getUrlVars() 
    {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
    }
</script>

<!--PHP TO SEND MAIL-->
<?php
   function submitfunc() 
    { }
?>
```

Help me out with this guys..:)

Thanks in advance

Comment: put it all in the  `$(document).ready` function...

Comment: Try to run it like this:  `setTimeout(function(){ $('#ContactForm').addClass('mailSent') }, 3000);` if its gonna work let me know...

Comment: Tried adding the Complete code in $(document).ready .Isn't helping.  Even added the setTimeout, The class isn't being added after 3 seconds. The page is the same.

Comment: @danavis  Fixed the issue guys....All that I had to do was place the Function definition before the declaration. And It worked...:):)..Thanks for all the help guys..

Answer (score 0):

Got an Answer to the Question guys, Leaving a reply jus in case someone in the future faces a simalar issue-

```
<script>
function getUrlVars() 
{
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

var first = getUrlVars()["action"];

if (first == 'submitfunc') 
{
    $('#ContactForm').addClass('mailSent');
} 
</script>
```

All that I had to do was place the Definition of the function before it was being used.
Thanks for all the help by @dandavis and @7urkm3n ..Cheers..:)